# Twemproxy GEOADD command

Tags: redis, twemproxy

From what I understand the `GEOADD` command / data structure is very similar to using `ZADD`.

When I run `GEOADD` through my `twemproxy` server, I get an error:

```
Error: Server closed the connection
```

If I issue the command directly to the redis servers themselves, it works fine.  Is there a way to run `GEOADD` / `GEORADIUS` through `twemproxy`?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @JohnPaulHayes I ended up moving on and using redis directly, as it wasn't a heavily used service. (Perhaps it's been fixed since?)